# Having a hard time converting angular code to Vue 3

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, migration

I need to migrate the angular 1 code to vue 3 with the composition api but without the script setup so it needs to be done with a return
this is the code

```
@{
    bool isAdmin = User.Identity.Name == "translation";
}
<div id="app">
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <div class="row">
       @if (isAdmin) { 
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" uib-dropdown-toggle>
                        <span v-if="!selectedClinic">Choose a clinic...</span>
                        <span v-if="selectedClinic">
                            {{selectedClinic.name}} - ID {{selectedClinic.clinicId}}
                        </span>
                        <span class="caret"></span>

                    </button>

                </div>

            </div>
       }
    </div>
    </div>
    @*<div class="row">
            @if (isAdmin)
            {
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" uib-dropdown-toggle>
                            <span v-if="!vm.selectedClinic">Choose a clinic...</span>
                            <span v-if="vm.selectedClinic">
                                {{::vm.selectedClinic.name}} - ID {{::vm.selectedClinic.clinicId}}
                            </span>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu>
                            <li v-for="c in vm.lookup.clinics">
                                <a href="#" ng-click="vm.selectClinic(c)">{{::c.name}} - ID {{::c.clinicId}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{vm.selectedClinic.publicKey}}" readonly />
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <h4>Translations for <strong>@ViewBag.Clinic.Name (@ViewBag.Clinic.ClinicId)</strong></h4>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <uib-tabset active="vm.activeTab">
                    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Items">
                        <table v-if="vm.activeTab == 0" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                            <tr>
                                <th>HS Id</th>
                                <th>HS Name</th>
                                <th>Type</th>
                                <th>Maps to</th>
                                <th>Package</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr v-for="i in vm.data.items">
                                <td class="col-xs-1">{{::i.hsId}}</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-3">{{::i.name}}</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-3">
                                    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="i.typeId" ng-options="s.id as s.title for s in vm.lookup.itemTypes"></select>
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-xs-4">
                                    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="i.chqId" ng-change="vm.saveItems(i)"
                                            ng-options="s.id as s.title for s in vm.lookup.masterItems[i.typeId]">
                                        <option value="">[Not Set]</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-xs-1 text-center">
                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.isPackage" ng-change="vm.saveItems(i)" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <div class="pagination form-inline">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.filterItems()">Refresh</button>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Records Per Page</span>
                                            <select class="form-control col-md-1" ng-model="vm.pageSize" chq-to-number ng-change="vm.filterItems()">
                                                <option value="50">50</option>
                                                <option value="100">100</option>
                                                <option value="150">150</option>
                                                <option value="200">200</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <div class="pull-right" ng-show="vm.totalItems > vm.pageSize">
                                        <ul uib-pagination ng-model="vm.currentPage"
                                            max-size="5"
                                            boundary-links="true"
                                            items-per-page="vm.pageSize"
                                            total-items="vm.totalItems"
                                            ng-change="vm.filterItems()"></ul>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="1" heading="Breeds">
                        <table v-if="vm.activeTab == 1" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Species</th>
                                <th>HS Breed</th>
                                <th>Maps to</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr v-for="b in vm.data.breeds">
                                <td class="col-xs-2">{{::b.speciesName}}</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-4">{{::b.name}}</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-4">
                                    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-change="vm.saveBreeds(b)" ng-model="b.chqId"
                                            ng-options="s.id as s.title for s in vm.lookup.breeds[b.chqSpeciesId]">
                                        <option value="">[Not Set]</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-xs-2">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="vm.saveBreeds(b)" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="b.isMixed" />
                                        Is Mixed
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="2" heading="Colors">
                        <table v-if="vm.activeTab == 2" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                            <tr>
                                <th>HS Color</th>
                                <th>Primary Color</th>
                                <th>Secondary Color</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr v-for="c in vm.data.colors">
                                <td class="col-xs-4">{{::c.name}}</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-4">
                                    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="c.chqPrimaryId"
                                            ng-change="vm.saveColors(c)"
                                            ng-options="s.id as s.title for s in vm.lookup.colors">
                                        <option value="">[Not Set]</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-xs-4">
                                    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="c.chqSecondaryId"
                                            ng-change="vm.saveColors(c)"
                                            ng-options="s.id as s.title for s in vm.lookup.colors">
                                        <option value="">[Not Set]</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="3" heading="Deceased Reasons">
                        <table v-if="vm.activeTab == 3" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                            <tr>
                                <th>HS Id</th>
                                <th>HS Name</th>
                                <th>Maps to</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr v-for="dc in vm.data.deathCauses">
                                <td>{{::dc.hsId}}</td>
                                <td>{{::dc.name}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="dc.chqId" ng-change="vm.saveDeathCauses(dc)"
                                                ng-options="s.id as s.title for s in vm.lookup.deathCauses"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="4" heading="Declined Reasons">
                        <table v-if="vm.activeTab == 4" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                            <tr>
                                <th>HS Id</th>
                                <th>HS Name</th>
                                <th>Maps to</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr v-for="dr in vm.data.declinedReasons">
                                <td>{{::dr.hsId}}</td>
                                <td>{{::dr.name}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="dr.chqId" ng-change="vm.saveDeclinedReasons(dr)"
                                                ng-options="s.id as s.title for s in vm.lookup.declinedSurgeryReasons"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="5" heading="Rabies Manufacturers">
                        <table v-if="vm.activeTab == 5" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                            <tr>
                                <th>HS Name</th>
                                <th>Maps to</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr v-for="r in vm.data.rabiesManufacturers">
                                <td>{{::r.name}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="r.chqId" ng-change="vm.saveManufacturers(r)"
                                                ng-options="s.id as s.title for s in vm.lookup.rabiesManufacturers"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="6" heading="Microchip Providers">
                        <table v-if="vm.activeTab == 6" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                            <tr>
                                <th>HS Id</th>
                                <th>HS Name</th>
                                <th>Maps to</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr v-for="mp in vm.data.microchipProviders">
                                <td>{{::mp.hsId}}</td>
                                <td>{{::mp.name}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="mp.chqId" ng-change="vm.saveMicrochipProviders(mp)"
                                                ng-options="s.id as s.title for s in vm.lookup.microchipProviders"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </uib-tab>
                </uib-tabset>
            </div>
        </div>*@
</div>

@section Scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">

        const { createApp, ref } = Vue

        createApp({
            setup() {
                const message = ref('Hello vue!')
                const selectedClinic = ref(null);
                const clinicId = ref('@(ViewBag.Clinic?.ClinicId)');
               
                return {
                    message,
                    selectedClinic,
                    clinicId
                }
            }
        }).mount('#app')

        @*(function () {

            var module = angular.module('hsApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

            module
                .directive('chqToNumber', function () {
                    return {
                        require: 'ngModel',
                        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (val) {
                                return parseInt(val, 10);
                            });
                            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (val) {
                                return '' + val;
                            });
                        }
                    };
                });

            module.controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);

            function Ctrl($http) {
                var vm = this,
                    allItems = [];

                vm.clinicId = '@(ViewBag.Clinic?.ClinicId)';
                vm.selectedClinic = null;

                vm.currentPage = 1;
                vm.pageSize = 50;
                vm.totalItems = 0;

                vm.lookup = {
                    clinics: [],
                    breeds: [],
                    colors: [],
                    deathCauses: [],
                    declinedSurgeryReasons: [],
                    rabiesManufacturers: [],
                    itemTypes: [],
                    microchipProviders: [],
                    masterItems: []
                };

                vm.data = {
                    breeds: [],
                    colors: [],
                    deathCauses: [],
                    declinedReasons: [],
                    rabiesManufacturers: [],
                    microchipProviders: [],
                    items: []
                };

                vm.saveItems = saveItems;
                vm.saveBreeds = saveBreeds;
                vm.saveColors = saveColors;
                vm.saveDeathCauses = saveDeathCauses;
                vm.saveDeclinedReasons = saveDeclinedReasons;
                vm.saveManufacturers = saveManufacturers;
                vm.saveMicrochipProviders = saveMicrochipProviders;

                vm.selectClinic = selectClinic;
                vm.filterItems = filterItems;

                init();

                function init() {
                    $http.get('/api/lookup')
                        .then(function (result) {
                             vm.lookup.clinics = result.data.clinics;
                             vm.lookup.breeds = result.data.breeds;
                             vm.lookup.colors = result.data.colors;
                             vm.lookup.deathCauses = result.data.deathCauses;
                             vm.lookup.declinedSurgeryReasons = result.data.declinedSurgeryReasons;
                             vm.lookup.rabiesManufacturers = result.data.rabiesManufacturers;
                             vm.lookup.itemTypes = result.data.itemTypes;
                             vm.lookup.microchipProviders = result.data.microchipProviders;
                             vm.lookup.masterItems = result.data.masterItems;

                             if (vm.clinicId) {
                                 loadClinicData();
                             }
                         });
                }

                function loadClinicData() {
                    if (!vm.clinicId) {
                        resetClinicData();
                        return;
                    }

                    $http.get('/api/data/' + vm.clinicId)
                         .then(function (result) {
                             vm.data.breeds = result.data.breeds;
                             vm.data.colors = result.data.colors;
                             vm.data.deathCauses = result.data.deathCauses;
                             vm.data.declinedReasons = result.data.declinedReasons;
                             vm.data.rabiesManufacturers = result.data.rabiesManufacturers;
                             vm.data.microchipProviders = result.data.microchipProviders;
                             allItems = result.data.items;

                             vm.totalItems = allItems.length;
                             vm.currentPage = 1;
                             filterItems();
                         });
                }

                function selectClinic(clinic) {
                    vm.clinicId = clinic.clinicId;
                    vm.selectedClinic = clinic;

                    loadClinicData();
                }

                function resetClinicData() {
                    vm.data.breeds.length = 0;
                    vm.data.colors.length = 0;
                    vm.data.deathCauses.length = 0;
                    vm.data.declinedReasons.length = 0;
                    vm.data.rabiesManufacturers.length = 0;
                    vm.data.microchipProviders.length = 0;
                    vm.data.items.length = 0;
                }

                function filterItems() {
                    vm.data.items = allItems.slice((vm.currentPage - 1) * vm.pageSize, vm.currentPage * vm.pageSize);
                }

                function saveItems(data) {
                    $http.post('/api/data/items', data).then(handleSuccess);
                }

                function saveBreeds(data) {
                    $http.post('/api/data/breeds', data).then(handleSuccess);
                }

                function saveColors(color) {
                    $http.post('/api/data/colors', color).then(handleSuccess);
                }

                function saveDeathCauses(data) {
                    $http.post('/api/data/deathCauses', data).then(handleSuccess);
                }

                function saveDeclinedReasons(data) {
                    $http.post('/api/data/declinedReasons', data).then(handleSuccess);
                }

                function saveManufacturers(data) {
                    $http.post('/api/data/manufacturers', data).then(handleSuccess);
                }

                function saveMicrochipProviders(data) {
                    $http.post('/api/data/providers', data).then(handleSuccess);
                }

                function handleSuccess() {

                }
            }
        })();*@
    </script>
}
```

I am having trouble converting the functions and the requests.I would be very thankful if anyone can help,As you can see i have started but it is going hard.I am a beginer and i need help.

Comment: the init function for example

Comment: "and show what you've tried".  what is the difficulty you're facing with it?  (The goal of my question is simply to figure out how someone can best help _you_ solve the problem, and not simply do it all for you)